# Как выполнить 1 синхронный поток, после 2 асинхронных

Tags: objective-c

На недавнем тех. интервью был задан вопрос "Есть три потока: 2 асинхронных и 1 синхронный, как их нужно выполнить, чтобы по завершению первых 2 асинхронных выполнился 1 синхронный?"

Comment: я может что не понял, как поток может быть синхронным или асинхронным?

Comment: может я не так пояснил, выполнить 2 dispatch_async и 1 dispatch_sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно создать группу асинхронных потоков. И после его окончания, вызвать синхронный поток.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
// Insert code here to initialize your application


dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();


dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    for (int i = 1; i < 9000; ++i) {
        NSLog(@"dispatch_async - 1: %i", i);
    };
});

dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    for (int i = 1; i < 9000; ++i) {
        NSLog(@"dispatch_async - 2: %i", i);
    };
});

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        for (int i = 1; i < 9000; ++i) {
            NSLog(@"dispatch_sync: %i", i);
        };
    });
});

NSLog(@"not dispatched code ****");
}
```